# Телефон в качестве модема

Tags: сеть, ubuntu, bluetooth

Здравствуйте! Поставил на нетбук ubuntu-10.04-netbook, есть телефон Nokia x6, как используя телефон в качестве модема по блютуз выходить в интернет? По шнуру через телефон все получается, он его видит в качестве модема и выходит в интернет. По блютузу ситуация такая, усстанавливаю связь с телефоном, он его соединяет, а после закрытия окна установки блютуза сбрасывает. Потом начинаю устанавливать сетевые соединения, он не видит телефон?

Answer (score 1):

Я точно в такой же версии убунты ставил blueman и с его помощью выходил в интернет через Acer E200. Стандартная блютус-подключалка какая-то не очень функциональная.

Comment: Как же мне его настроить?

Comment: Т.Е. через репозиторий ставить blueman, опишите пожалуйста как мне сделать?

Comment: Смотрите здесь: [Менеджер bluetooth - Blueman](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/blueman).